# Laravel/MySQL Hitting Lookup Id Endpoint Returning Null JSON Body

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-10

I am having a issue hitting an endpoint in my API and getting the correct JSON response in a firefox.

I am attempting to hit https://...locationtypes/1 and getting this JSON response:

```
{
    "data": {
        "id": null,
        "name": null
    }
}
```

Here is a response from hitting https://...locationtypes:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Event"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Vendor"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Utility"
        }
}
```

LocationType.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class LocationType extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name'
    ];

    public function locations() {
        return $this->hasMany(Location::class);
    }

public function resolveRouteBinding($value, $field = null)
    {
        return $this->where('id', $value)->firstOrFail();
    }
}
```

LocationTypeController.php (show and store method):

```
public function store(StoreLocationTypeRequest $request)
    {
        return new LocationTypeResource(LocationType::create($request->all()));
    }

public function show(LocationType $locationType)
    {
        $includeLocations = request()->query('includeLocations');

        if ($includeLocations) {
            return new LocationTypeResource($locationType->loadMissing('locations'));
        }
        return new LocationTypeResource($locationType);
    }
```

LocationTypeResource.php:

```
class LocationTypeResource extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @return array<string, mixed>
     */
    public function toArray(Request $request): array
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'name' => $this->name,
            'locations' => LocationResource::collection($this->whenLoaded('locations'))
        ];
    }
}
```

api.php:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'v1'], function () {
    // CRUD
    Route::apiResource('events', EventController::class);
    Route::apiResource('info', InfoController::class);
    Route::apiResource('locations', LocationController::class);
    //Route::apiResource('locationtypes', LocationTypeController::class);
    Route::get('locationtypes', [LocationTypeController::class, 'index']);
    Route::get('locationtypes/{id}', [LocationTypeController::class, 'show']);

    // Bulk POST
    Route::post('events/bulk', ['uses'=>'EventController@bulkStore']);
    Route::post('info/bulk', ['uses'=>'InfoController@bulkStore']);
    Route::post('locations/bulk', ['uses'=>'LocationController@bulkStore']);
    Route::post('locationtypes/bulk', ['uses'=>'LocationTypeController@bulkStore']);

});
```

I apologize if I have forgotten something, I am new to Laravel still. Also, this is Laravel 10. To clarify the problem, I cannot figure out why the id endpoint is spewing null back at me.

EDIT: I was able to use Route::get(locationtypes/{locationType}) to obtain the desired output by using the 'name' field but I am still unable to use the 'id' field and get null as output. I edited the above code to display my changes.

Comment: What you are looking at is "RouteModelBinding". Normally, this is done automatically by Laravel. My guess is that laravel is unable to fetch your model by the provided id. You could add a [`resolveRouteBinding`](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/routing#customizing-the-resolution-logic) function, in your model, to customize the query used to retreive the model from the database using the id. This might help figure out why it is not working.

Comment: Could I possibly see an example of that method? I do not completely understand the docs.

Comment: So, I was able to get a location type by name but not by id... I still get the same issue. Any idea why that would be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Nicolas is on the right track, it's a route model binding issue.

Your route parameter is `{id}`

```
Route::get('locationtypes/{id}', [LocationTypeController::class, 'show']);
```

But it needs to match the type-hinted variable name in your controller's show method

```
public function show(LocationType $locationType)
```

It should work if you update your route to:

```
Route::get('locationtypes/{locationType}', [LocationTypeController::class, 'show']);
```

**Note:**
I'm not 100% sure if the case in the route should be snake, camel or kebab. I think it's snake but not certain So where your controller variable is camel cased `locationType` your route parameter may need to be snake `{location_type}` or kebab `{location-type}` or camel `{locationType}`. You may need to try each until you fin the one that works.
Annoyingly, Laravel's docs aren't explicitly clear about that point.

**Edit:**
It appears as though there is no case conversation so whatever you use for your variable name in the controller should *exactly* match your route parameter name. So:

`$locationType` = `{locationType}`

`$location_type` = `{location_type}`

`$locationtype` = `{locationtype}`

etc.

Comment: I have tried this and I get a 404 not found when using anything but {id} while trying to lookup by id. I have found in the laravel logs that I am getting some weird errors that some of my tables do not exist, although they do and I can see them. I am going to try a fresh project altogether. I will come back and update this if it works.

Comment: I did miss in your question you define a `resolveRouteBinding` method on your `LocationType`. Try commenting that method out with my solution above, Laravel should handle the route model binding implicitly as long as you're matching the variable and parameter names correctly

Comment: You were completely right... fixing my parameters in my Controller from "locationType" to "locationtype" fixed the issue.

Comment: Yeah, it is just a question of matching the route parameter to the type-hinted variable name in the controller. Interesting that you had to make the controller variable all lower-case. You should be able to use `locationType` as long as you find the right case to use in the route parameter. Please don't forget to mark the answer as accepted if it solved your problem